# Permanently remove solution from SourceSafe?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution that is checked in to Microsoft Visual SourceSafe.  I need to remove the solution from my SourceSafe database and add it to another SourceSafe database.

To that end, I have downloaded the project onto my workstation from SourceSafe and I want to remove all SourceSafe associations from the solution so that I can check it in to the new SourceSafe DB.

I tried removing all the scc and vsscc files from the solution, but that doesn't work.  It seems that there ought to be a simple way to accomplish what I want.

Please advise.

Comment: Related: [visual source safe - how to remove bindings from solution w/o opening in visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019664/visual-source-safe-how-to-remove-bindings-from-solution-w-o-opening-in-visual)

Comment: And it sounds like your question should be: Permanently remove SourceSafe *bindings* from Solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the bindings in the solution from the first VSS.

1. Checkout the solution in VS2010.
2. Use the Solution Explorer to make sure that the solution file is selected File > Source Control > Change Source Control
3. In the dialog unbind all the projects and solution, tick all the items then click Disconnect

After this you can of course check it into another VSS database AND you'll still need to delete it from the first VSS database, but I believe this is what you were really asking about.