# How to disconnect project solution from TFS in Visual Studio 2017 or 2019?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, azure-devops

I have a solution which was connected with TFS. Whenever I try to install new library in the solution, I get an error:

> Unauthorised (410)

I have tried to delete all TFS-related files from solution, but I'm still getting that same error.

Has anyone faced the same issue and resolved it somehow?

Comment: edit .sln file and remove tfs section

Answer (score 6):

Verified solution

**SOLUTION 1**

For permanently and completely detach the solution from source control, Do the following steps:

1. Click the 'No' button to avoid connecting to TFS.
2. In the file menu, go to the source control options and clear the bindings. You'll specifically want `File menu - Source Control - Advanced - Change Source Control...`
3. Save the solution.

Next time you open the solution you won't be prompted to connect to TFS.

**SOLUTION 2**

To completely remove TFS source control binding follow these two steps:

1. Go to your solution's folder, find and delete all files with `*.vssscc` and `*.vspscc` extensions.
2. Open your solution's `.sln` file in Notepad, and find & remove the `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)` section.

[Reference Link](https://theprogressiveviews.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-completely-remove-tfs-source.html)

From: [Remove TFS Connection From Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990033/remove-tfs-connection-from-solution/35147322#35147322)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, errors starting with 4XX is caused by wrong credentials. With that perspective, you can try disconnect from the server then reconnect via from  Team->Disconnect from server

Also unbind the project and bind again;
File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have deleted all related files locally. To completely remove TFS source control binding follow these two steps:

1. Go to your solution's folder, find and delete all files with
   `*.vssscc` and `*.vspscc` extensions.
2. Open your solution's `.sln` file in Notepad, and find & remove the
   `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)` section.

`GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
<code>    SccNumberOfProjects = 2
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = <YourTFSURL>
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = .
    SccLocalPath1 = .
EndGlobalSection`

More detail steps please take a look at this blog here: [Reference Link](https://theprogressiveviews.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-completely-remove-tfs-source.html) .

If you still get issue, also close VS, [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/). Then open VS again, which may do the trick.