# TFS binding shows status as invalid after reinstalling windows

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2019, solution

Our projects are showing binding status as Invalid. 
The problem started when we reinstalled our windows OS.

Steps which I took :
In the **VS 2019**, I created a new workspace & mapped the TFS server folder to local existing folder(It was working previously with TFS before windows re-installation).
After saving new workspace it asked me to get the latest version, which I did. 
Now under *Team Explorer > Pending changes > Excluded changes* - it shows me **Detected (some number) adds** (which is whole solution files & folders).

Under Solution Explorer If I right click on any file or folder of this project it shows me - **Add files to Source Control**.

Somewhere I read to bind solutions, to which I followed this step:
*File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control*.

Here on all of the Solution/Project I clicked on Bind - The **status** shows for all as **Invalid**.

Please someone help me on this. As, I have multiple solutions & all of them have the same issue. They did had pending changes too.

Answer (score 0):

If rebinding doesn't work, you might try editing the solution files directly.

To completely remove TFS source control binding follow these two steps:

1. Go to your solution's folder, find and delete all files with `*.vssscc` and `*.vspscc` extensions.
2. Open your solution's `.sln` file in Notepad, and find & remove the `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)` section.

Below is a sample section that has references to Scc:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 1
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = http://yourtfs:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = WebApplication\\WebApplication.csproj
    SccProjectName1 = WebApplication
    SccLocalPath1 = WebApplication
EndGlobalSection
```

[Reference Link](https://theprogressiveviews.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-completely-remove-tfs-source.html)

From: [Remove TFS Connection From Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990033/remove-tfs-connection-from-solution/35147322#35147322)

After this, you could try to add whole solutions to source control or  **Bind the solution file to TFS again**

> Finally bind the solution file (.sln) to TFS again. Do this in visual
>   studio by going to the menu`File => Source Control => Change Source
>   Control
>
> [image: Binding the solution file to TFS again]

More another ways, you could take a look at the solution in this similar question: [Re-establish TFS source control bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128730/re-establish-tfs-source-control-bindings)